How can run rdesktop command in background?
In my local area network,it can connect remote desktop in 192.168.1.5:
rdesktop  -u user  -p password   192.168.1.5:3389


I want to execute rdesktop command in background.
rdesktop  -u user  -p password   192.168.1.5:3389  &

It can't work.
 rdesktop  -u user  -p password   192.168.1.5:3389  &
[1] 34297
debian@MiWiFi-R4A-srv:~$ Core(warning): Certificate received from server is NOT trusted by this system, an exception has been added by the user to trust this specific certificate.
Failed to initialize NLA, do you have correct Kerberos TGT initialized ?
Core(warning): Certificate received from server is NOT trusted by this system, an exception has been added by the user to trust this specific certificate.
Connection established using SSL.

Try with nohup
nohup "rdesktop  -u user  -p password   192.168.1.5:3389" > out.log 2>err.log  &
[1] 34560

No error info ,but no windows desktop in 192.168.1.5.
How can run rdesktop command in background?
